# How to create procedure for this problem

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a procedure to send data from one table (`abc`) to another table (`xyz`) and that data is moved to second table(`xyz`) only when that data is deleted from 1st table (`abc`)...

```
insert into copydelete (usernm  ,pas ,scholor)
  select username,pasword,scholorship from administraor where username= 'sunil' ;

delete from administraor  where username='sunil' ;
```

Comment: Its very difficult to understand your question. I am guessing that you are probably looking for a trigger based solution as described [**here**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54897/8783).

Comment: Your statements looks ok provided that you are using a transaction, what's wrong with them?

Comment: @Lennart ok, except for the missing `;` which make it rather confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx).  Here's a simple demo:

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('copydelete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE copydelete
CREATE TABLE copydelete
(
    usernm  VARCHAR(20),
    pas VARCHAR(20),
    scholor BIT,

    dateAdded DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    addedBy VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT SUSER_NAME()
)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('administraor') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE administraor
CREATE TABLE administraor
(
    username VARCHAR(20),
    pasword VARCHAR(20),
    scholorship BIT
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.administraor VALUES 
    ( 'sunil', 'a', 1 ),
    ( 'wBob', 'b', 0 )
GO

SELECT 'before' s, * FROM dbo.administraor

INSERT INTO dbo.copydelete ( usernm, pas, scholor )
SELECT username, pasword, scholorship
FROM
    (
    DELETE dbo.administraor
    OUTPUT deleted.username, deleted.pasword, deleted.scholorship 
    WHERE username = 'sunil'
    ) x


SELECT 'after' s, * FROM dbo.administraor
SELECT 'after' s, * FROM dbo.copydelete
```