# Passing info on who deleted record onto a Delete trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, audit

In setting up an audit trail I have no problem tracking who is updating or inserting records in a table, however, tracking who deletes records seems more problematic.

I can track Inserts/Updates by including in the Insert/Update the field "UpdatedBy". This allows the INSERT/UPDATE trigger to have access to the field "UpdatedBy" via `inserted.UpdatedBy`. However, with the Delete trigger no data is inserted/updated. Is there a way to pass information onto the Delete trigger such that it could know who deleted the record?

Here is an Insert/Update trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_MyTable_InsertUpdate] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS  

INSERT INTO AuditTable (IdOfRecordedAffected, UserWhoMadeChanges) 
VALUES (inserted.ID, inserted.LastUpdatedBy)
FROM inserted
```

Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: See [**this**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54897/8783) answer. `SUSER_SNAME()` is the key to get who deleted record.

Comment: Thanks Kin, however I don't think `SUSER_SNAME()` would work in a situation like a web application where a single user might be used for database communication for the entire application.

Comment: You did not mention that you were calling a web app.

Comment: Sorry Kin, I should have been more specific to the application type.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way to pass information onto the Delete trigger such that it could know who deleted the record?

Yes: by using a *very* cool (and under utilized feature) called `CONTEXT_INFO`. It is essentially session memory that exists in all scopes and is not bound by transactions. It can be used to pass info (any info--well, any that fits into the limited space) to triggers as well as back and forth between sub-proc / EXEC calls. And I have used it before for this exact same situation.

- Context info is a VARBINARY(128)
- Set via: [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx)
- Get via: [CONTEXT_INFO()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx)

Test with the following to see how it works. Notice that I am converting to `CHAR(128)` before the `CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), ..`.  This is to force blank-padding to make it easier to convert back to `VARCHAR` when getting it out of `CONTEXT_INFO()` since `VARBINARY(128)` is right-padded with `0x00`s.

```sql
SELECT CONTEXT_INFO();
-- Initially = NULL

DECLARE @EncodedUser VARBINARY(128);
SET @EncodedUser = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128),
                            CONVERT(CHAR(128), 'I deleted ALL your records! HA HA!')
                          );
SET CONTEXT_INFO @EncodedUser;

SELECT CONTEXT_INFO() AS [RawContextInfo],
       RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), CONTEXT_INFO())) AS [DecodedUser];
```

Results:

```
0x492064656C6574656420414C4C20796F7572207265636F7264732120484120484121202020202020...
I deleted ALL your records! HA HA!
```

**PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER:**

1. The app should call a "Delete" stored procedure that passes in the UserName (or whatever) that is deleting the record. I assume this is already the model being used since it sounds like you are already tracking Insert and Update operations.
2. The "Delete" stored procedure does:

   ```
   DECLARE @EncodedUser VARBINARY(128);
   SET @EncodedUser = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128),
                               CONVERT(CHAR(128), @UserName)
                             );
   SET CONTEXT_INFO @EncodedUser;

   -- DELETE STUFF HERE
   ```
3. The audit trigger does:

   ```
   -- Set the INT value in LEFT (currently 50) to the max size of [UserWhoMadeChanges]
   INSERT INTO AuditTable (IdOfRecordedAffected, UserWhoMadeChanges) 
      SELECT del.ID, COALESCE(
                        LEFT(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), CONTEXT_INFO())), 50),
                        '<unknown>')
      FROM DELETED del;
   ```
4. Please note that, as @SeanGallardy pointed out in a comment, due to other procedures and/or ad hoc queries deleting records from this table, it is possible that either:

   - `CONTEXT_INFO` has not been set and is still `NULL`:

     For this reason I have updated the above `INSERT INTO AuditTable` to use a `COALESCE` to default the value. Or, if you don't want a default and require a name, then you could do something similar to:

     ```
     DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(50); -- set to the size of AuditTable.[UserWhoMadeChanges]
     SET @UserName = LEFT(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), CONTEXT_INFO())), 50);

     IF (@UserName IS NULL)
     BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN; -- cancel the DELETE operation
        RAISERROR('Please set UserName via "SET CONTEXT_INFO.." and try again.', 16 ,1);
     END;

     -- use @UserName in the INSERT...SELECT
     ```
   - `CONTEXT_INFO` has been set to a value that is *not* a valid UserName, and hence might exceed the size of the `AuditTable.[UserWhoMadeChanges]` field:

     For this reason I added a `LEFT` function to ensure that whatever is grabbed out of `CONTEXT_INFO` will not break the `INSERT`. As noted in the code, you just need to set the `50` to the actual size of the `UserWhoMadeChanges` field.

---

**UPDATE FOR SQL SERVER 2016 AND NEWER**

SQL Server 2016 added an improved version of this per-session memory: Session Context. The new Session Context is essentially a hash table of Key-Value pairs with the "Key" being of type `sysname` (i.e. `NVARCHAR(128)` ) and the "Value" being `SQL_VARIANT`. Meaning:

1. There is now a separation of values so less likely to conflict with other uses
2. You can store various types, no longer needing to worry about the odd behavior when getting the value back out via `CONTEXT_INFO()` (for details, please see my post: [Why Doesn’t CONTEXT_INFO() Return the Exact Value Set by SET CONTEXT_INFO?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/04/09/why-doesnt-context_info-return-the-exact-value-set-by-set-context_info/))
3. You get *a lot* more space: 8000 bytes max per "Value", up to 256kb total across all keys (compared to the 128 bytes max of `CONTEXT_INFO`)

For details, please see the following documentation pages:

- [sp_set_session_context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql)
- [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is VERY volatile. Any session can set this, as such it can overwrite any previously set item. Want to really break your application? have a single dev overwrite what you expect. I would highly advise NOT to use this and have a standard approach which may require an architecture change. Otherwise, you're playing with fire.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Can you please provide an actual example of this happening? Session == `@@SPID`. This is PER-Session/Connection memory. One session cannot overwrite another session's context info. And when the session logs off the value goes away. There is no such thing as a "previously set item".

Comment: I didn't say "another session's" I said any object in the session scope can do this. So, one dev writes a sproc to hold his own "contextual" information and now yours is overwritten. There was an application I had to deal with that used this same pattern, I've watched it happen... it was HR software. Let me tell you how happy people were to NOT be paid on time due to a "bug" by one of the devs writing a new SP that erroneously updated the context info for the session from what it was "supposed" to be. Just giving an example I've actually witnessed of why not to use this method.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Ok, thanks for clarifying that point. But it is still only a partially valid point. In order for that situation to happen, that "other" proc would have to be called inside of this one. Or, if you are talking about some other proc that might be deleting from this table and kicking off the trigger, that is something that can be tested for. It is a race condition, which is something to be accounted for (just as they are in all multithreaded apps), and not a reason to not use this technique. And so I will make a minor update to do just that. Thank you for bringing this possiblity up.

Comment: It's not a problem if it's just a single person dev team, you won't step on each other. when it's a larger team and devs start to "know" this exists, they all start using it. If this is *all* it's ever used for in a single place, it will most likely work without issue. I would rather architect the system differently to take auditing into account rather than have it be an after thought with a shim.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I get what you're saying, but that's still not a reason to not use this, even with large / multiple teams. This is why we have code reviews, QA, and communication. Yes, it's a shared-resource and there can be conflicts, but the database is also a shared resource and tables/fields can be misused. I have seen it happen where one team used a table for a "similar" purpose and it appeared to work but did not account for some side-effects and added 764 rows (480 GB) to a table that was already 223 rows (135 GB). But I still use tables. However, I added a new CONTEXT_INFO-free answer :)

Comment: I'm saying security as an after thought is the main problem and this isn't the tool to solve it. Memo structures or other uses that don't break the application, sure I have no problem. It absolutely is a reason to NOT use it. YMMV but I would never use something so volatile and unstructured for something that is important such as security. Using any type of shared user writable storage for security is a terrible idea overall. Proper design would remove the need for things such as this, for the most part.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I forgot to mention earlier that this isn't necessarily "security as an after thought". Handling security purely from an app perspective allows for DML operations against the tables that don't go through "approved" code paths that handle the auditing. People write code that doesn't do the audit, ad hoc queries, etc. Also, there is nothing to say that there is any functional tie-in to these audit tables. Why assume that any random value would break the app? But again, this is why test, test, and test.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I just updated to add info about Session Context that was added in SQL Server 2016. I think that Session Context takes care of your volatility concerns, both in terms of having different values, and the ability to mark a value as read-only :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can't that way, unless you are looking to record the SQL server user ID rather than an application level one.

You can do a soft delete by having a column called DeletedBy and setting that as needed, then your update trigger can do the real delete (or archive the record, I generally avoid hard deletes where possible and legal) as well as updating your audit trail. To force deletes to be done that way define an `on delete` trigger that raises an error. If you don't want to add a column to your physical table, you could define a view that adds the column and define `instead of` triggers to handle updating the base table, but that may be overkill.

Comment: I see your point. I would indeed be looking to log the application level user.

Comment: David, actually you can pass info to triggers. Please see my answer for details :).

Comment: Good suggestion here, I really like this route.  Kills two birds by capturing Who in the same step as triggering the real delete.  Since this column is going to be NULL for every record in this table, it seems like it would be a good use of the SQL Server `SPARSE` column?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to pass information onto the Delete trigger such that it could know who deleted the record?

Yes, apparently there are two ways ;-). If there are any reservations about using `CONTEXT_INFO` as I have suggested in [my other answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82615/passing-info-on-who-deleted-record-onto-a-delete-trigger/82627#82627), I just thought of another way that has a cleaner functional separation from other code / processes: use a local temporary table.

The temp table name should include the table name being deleted from as that will help keep it separate from any other code that might happen to run in the same session. Something along the lines of:
`#<TableName>DeleteAudit`

One benefit to a local temp table over `CONTEXT_INFO` is that if someone in another proc--that is somehow call from this particular "Delete" proc--just happens to incorrect use the same temp table name, the subprocess will a) create a new local temp table of the requested name that will be separate from this initial temp table (even though it has the same name), and b) any DML statements against the new local temp table in the sub-process won't affect any data in the local temp table created here in the parent process, hence no overwriting of data. Of course, if a subprocess issues a DML statement against this temp table name without first issuing a CREATE TABLE of that same name, then those DML statements *will* affect the data in this table. BUT, at this point we are getting *really* edge-casey here, even more so than with the probability of overlapping uses of `CONTEXT_INFO` (yes, I know it has happened, which is why I say "edge-case" rather than "it'll never happen").

1. The app should call a "Delete" stored procedure that passes in the UserName (or whatever) that is deleting the record. I assume this is already the model being used since it sounds like you are already tracking Insert and Update operations.
2. The "Delete" stored procedure does:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #MyTableDeleteAudit (UserName VARCHAR(50));
   INSERT INTO #MyTableDeleteAudit (UserName) VALUES (@UserName);

   -- DELETE STUFF HERE
   ```
3. The audit trigger does:

   ```
   -- Set the datatype and length to be the same as the [UserWhoMadeChanges] field
   DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(50);
   IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TriggerTestDeleteAudit') IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
      SELECT @UserName = UserName
      FROM #TriggerTestDeleteAudit;
   END;

   -- catch the following conditions: missing table, no rows in table, or empty row
   IF (@UserName IS NULL OR @UserName NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%')
   BEGIN
     /* -- uncomment if undefined UserName == badness
      ROLLBACK TRAN; -- cancel the DELETE operation
      RAISERROR('Please set UserName via #TriggerTestDeleteAudit and try again.', 16 ,1);
      RETURN; -- exit
     */
     /* -- uncomment if undefined UserName gets default value
      SET @UserName = '<unknown>';
     */
   END;

   INSERT INTO AuditTable (IdOfRecordedAffected, UserWhoMadeChanges) 
      SELECT del.ID, @UserName
      FROM DELETED del;
   ```

   I have tested this code in a trigger and it works as expected.